# What is the overhead/cost of creating __block variables rather than regular (heap/stack allocations)

Tags: objective-c

The performance and/or memory implications of creating a variable like this:

```
__block NSMutableArray *objects = nil;
```

Instead of this:

```
NSMutableArray *objects = nil;
```

It can't be much, but for curiosity's sake, does anyone know or have a good guess?

Comment: Create two functions, one containing the first declaration and one containing the second declaration, then compare the assembly generated by the compiler.    There is overhead associated with the __block in that said variable may need to outlive the scope within which it is declared and, thus, there is some indirection going on.

Comment: Block values live on the heap and the block saves a reference to it. It's hard to tell if this has any significant impact. You can write a performance test and check it ;)